# Script to look for a word in file1 and copy the next word and replace that in file2

Tags: python, powershell, shell, awk, sed

I have **file1**

```
(1'a lot of singapore 1.2.3.4 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(2,'a lot of brazil  4.2.3.1, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(3,'a lot of india 3.4.2.1, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(4,'a lot of laos 1.3.4.5, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(5,'a lot of china 1.2.3.5, 'some other info',0,null, 12345);
```

and **file2**

```
(1'a lot of singapore A.B.C.D 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(2,'a lot of brazil E.F.G.H, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(3,'a lot of india H.I.J.K, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(4,'a lot of laos L.M.N.O, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(5,'a lot of china P.Q.R.S, 'some other info',0,null, 12345);
```

I have created a  script but to copy and replace with LINE number but need input to look for `SINGAPORE` in file 1 and copy next word `1.2.3.4` and look for `singapore` in file2 and replace the next word here from `1.2.3.4` - `A.B.C.D` and the final file2 looks like this

```
(1'a lot of singapore 1.2.3.4 'some other info',0,null, 12345),
```

Python script or Awk or `sed` any script will be helpful.

So far I have created this to copy and replace line numbers

```
sed -i '2d' File2.txt
awk 'NR==5380{a=$0}NR==FNR{next}FNR==2{print a}1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple Awk script to look for the replacement text from the first input file and replace the corresponding token in the second input file.

```
awk -v country="singapore" 'NR == FNR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($(i-1) == country) token = $i; next }
  $0 ~ country { for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($(i-1) == country) $i = token
    } 1' file1 file2 >newfile2
```

When we are reading `file1`, `NR == FNR` is true. We loop over the input tokens and check for one which matches `country`; if we find one, we set `token` to that value. This means that if there are multiple matches on the country keyword, the last one in the first input file will be extracted.

The `next` statement causes Awk to skip the rest of the script for this input file, so the lines from `file1` are only read, and not processed further.

If we fall through to the last line, we are now reading `file2`. If we see a line which contains the keyword, we perform a substitution on the keyword after the `country` keyword. (This requires the keyword to be an isolated token, not a substring within a longer word etc.) The final `1` causes all lines which get this far to be printed back to standard output, thus generating a copy of the second file with any substitutions performed.

If you have any control over the data format used here, perhaps try to figure out a way to get the input in a less haphazard ad-hoc format, like JSON.

Comment: Hello thank you this script is working good for one string ie singapore if i want to copy and replace multiple strings like singapore , laos , india etc then how to do that?

Comment: If you want to look for it anywhere in the line, probably create a regex out of the words, like `-v country="laos|singapore|india"` and change the condition to `$(i-1) ~ country`. If in fact, reading between the lines, you actually want to examine a particular field at a fixed position in the file, there is a mound of existing questions about joining files with Awk; but if you need further help, perhaps (accept one of the answers you received here, and) ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work and it's the best solution, but you need something like this.

```
import re

def try_to_get_country_data(line, country):
    line_parts = line.split(',')
    part_with_data = line_parts[1]
    
    if (match := re.search(f'.* {country} (.*)', part_with_data)) is not None:
        return match.group(1)
    
    return None
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    found_data = None
    country = 'singapore'

    with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if (found_data := try_to_get_country_data(line, country)) is not None:
                break

    if found_data is not None:
        with open('second_file.txt', 'r') as f2:
            data = f2.readlines()

        for i, line in enumerate(data):
            if (replaced_data := try_to_get_country_data(line, country)) is not None:
                data[i] = line.replace(replaced_data, found_data)
                break

        with open('second_file.txt', 'w') as f2:
            f2.writelines(data)
```

So, I've checked it, and it work if line pattern same for each line.

Answer (score -1):

In case you would like a short `bash` script and assuming that the structure of the files is constant you could try something like this:

```
country="singapore"
a=$(grep "${country}" file0 | awk '{print $5}')

if [[ "${a}" ]]
then
    b=$(grep -w "${country}" file1 | awk '{print $5}')
    sed "s/${country} ${b}/${country} ${a}/g" file1
fi
```

Find below the output of the script:

```
(1'a lot of singapore 1.2.3.4 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(2,'a lot of brazil E.F.G.H, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(3,'a lot of india H.I.J.K, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(4,'a lot of laos L.M.N.O, 'some other info',0,null, 12345),

(5,'a lot of china P.Q.R.S, 'some other info',0,null, 12345);
```

Use `sed -i` in order to edit `file1` in place.

In order to avoid reading the same file multiple times and reducing a little bit the readability, the initial approach may be easily refactored as follows:

```
country="singapore"
file0c=$(cat file0)
file1c=$(cat file1)

a=$(echo "${file1c}" | grep -w "${country}" | awk '{print $5}')

if [[ "${a}" ]]
then
    b=$(echo "${file1c}" | grep -w "${country}" | awk '{print $5}')
    echo "${file1c}" | sed "s/${country} ${b}/${country} ${a}/g" | 
    tee file1_new
fi
```

Comment: Repeatedly reading the same files to pull out a single token somewhere is extremely inelegant and inefficient. This could be refactored to a single Awk script which reads each file once and produces the result while looping over the input.

Comment: Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); anything which looks like `grep x | awk '{ y }'` can usefully be refactored to `awk '/x/ { y }'`

Comment: I'm afraid the recent edit only adds complexity, not improvements.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for your comments! For sure my approach is not that elegant but is simple, short and clear enough in order a new bash/awk/sed/grep user to understand each command.